# Guidelines to stop horizontal scrolling in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, overflow

I realize this question has been asked before but the solution that is usually supplied involves adding this to the target tag:

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

which I've done. This fix prevents horizontal scrolling in Firefox but fails when it comes to Chrome and IE8 (not so much an issue at this moment in regard to IE8). Judging by previous questions this may have become an issue since Chrome version 34. So how do I go about fixing this?

Thr problem CSS that is causing the scrolling looks like this:

```
// Tablet portrait and landscape
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    & {
        margin: 0 -100% !important;
        padding: 30px 100% !important;
    }
}
```

the above causes the content to appear evenly in the center as per the requirement. Any advice on this or a possible resource to explain why this happens in Chrome?

Thanks

P.S. I also noticed that this site doesn't have that problem - why would that be? Fundamental difference in structure? Or the CSS I'm looking for?

Comment: What is the logic of that code ??? margin `-100%` and padding `100%` ????

Comment: That isn't pure CSS. What preprocessor is that?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly its LESS

Comment: @Katana24 I've added the LESS tag to your question.

Comment: What element are you applying this too? Can you provide an example of the issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with CSS, but with how you're typing it.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly This question has nothing to do with LESS...

Comment: That being said, you might want to show your actual output CSS rather than your unprocessed LESS @Katana24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's efforts even though I provided little information. We solved the error though we still don't know why it was happening. We have different .LESS files for different pages but they are all imported into one called **ice-styles.less**

Here was were I was adding the `overflow-x: hidden` and for some reason this was being ignored even with an **!important** suffix appended. My understanding of this was that it should apply to all pages because it was being attached to the **html** and **body** tags.

So we moved the same line above into the .LESS page that the problem was occurring and it fixed the problem - but it didn't introduce the problem into other pages - this suggests that the structure of the page was the real culprit.

Thanks again everyone

Answer (score 0):

did you tried styling it by jquery?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').css('overflow-x','hidden !important');
})

or even if it didnt worked trying it after few seconds
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeOut(function(){
$('body').css('overflow-x','hidden !important');
},1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

there is something that is overwriting you overflow:hidden tag...
maybe there is some css that gives your element some width and then you force the overflow which does not happen at times in chrome or IE...

Answer (score -2):

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden; //or none
}
```

Comment: i already said I used hidden above - none doesn't work either